# ERROR of Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

Tags: react-native, android-build

I get a duplicate error after running `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` and consecutively  `react-native run-android --variant=release`.

Deleting the duplicate resources by running `rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*` actually helps. However, my changes doesn't get bundled after deleting those files. Hence, when I run `react-native run-android --variant=release` again, my changes isn't effected in the build.

Answer (score 0):

Only the `drawable_*` delete.

android/app/sec/main/res/ and it work.

Or

- Generate keystore
- Place keystore under your project/android/app/
- Edit android/gradle.properties file with your password for keystore
- Edit android/app/build.gradle in your project folder and add the
  signing config
- Run this code in the command line cd android && gradlew
  assembleRelease

If you run into a problem in building APK like this error:
Unable to process incoming event 'ProgressComplete ' (ProgressCompleteEvent)

I recommend to

- upgrade gradle to 4.3 to avoid building problems
- or use Gradlew.bat assembleRelease instead

Comment: please mark it as accepted if it helped. Thanks!

Comment: @marvelous-ikechi If this answer does not help you, let me know so we can explore better ways together.